# How should I handle state in this Activity?

Tags: android

When I press the back button, while my app's running, the `onPause` method gets called, but the `onSaveInstanceState` isn't. Then, if I enter my app again, I receive a call to `onCreate`, which will re-run my initialization logic.

I would like to save the state, so I can restore it when the user enters the app again, however I'm not sure how to go about this. What use will the `onCreate`'s `Bundle` be to me, since in `onPause` I can only save data through `SharedPreferences`? Or I shouldn't rely on the `Bundle` at all, and just reinitialize from the `SharedPreferences`?

How could the reinitialization be handled best?

EDIT: I would prefer if the changes could persist only until the app is killed. Only for the application's lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the onSaveInstanceState [API Page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

> If called, this method will occur before onStop(). There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause().

As long as your activity is being killed and you have overridden the onSaveInstanceState correctly then it should be fired.

As for your recent edit (from the same API page)

> Called to retrieve per-instance state from an activity before being killed so that the state can be restored in onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) (the Bundle populated by this method will be passed to both).

onSaveInstanceState is best used for persisting state when an activity is killed, not so much just for storing state for the application's lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the onSaveInstanceState documentation:

> Do not confuse this method with activity lifecycle callbacks such as
>   onPause(), which is always called when an activity is being placed in
>   the background or on its way to destruction, or onStop() which is
>   called before destruction. One example of when onPause() and onStop()
>   is called and not this method is when a user navigates back from
>   activity B to activity A: there is no need to call
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) on B because that particular instance will
>   never be restored, so the system avoids calling it.

This should answer your question :)